# Jquery find next input, select on keypress but not button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to select the next input:visible and select:visible when the user press "enter".  My code work except it finds the next `button` element and I don't want that.

```
$(document).on('keypress', 'input, select', function (e) {
if (e.which == 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
            var inputs = $(this).closest('form').find(':input:visible, select:visible');
          inputs.eq( inputs.index(this)+ 1 ).focus();
    }
});
```

How to filter the button ?

Thanks

Comment: is your input is having type button in form ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `:not` to exclude some elements:

```
var inputs = $(this).closest('form').find(':input:not(button,[type="button"],[type="submit"]):visible, select:visible');
```

This gets quite verbose though. A better solution may be to put a common class on the `input` and `select` elements you *do* want to find and select that, eg `.foo:visible`

Comment: thanks, I've got `Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: button,[type=["button"],[type="submit"]`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
if(inputs.eq( inputs.index(this)+ 1 ).prop("type") != "button")
    inputs.eq( inputs.index(this)+ 1 ).focus();
```

hope it works

Comment: Now the cursor block when it encounter a `button`.  But thanks !